# Neo4j BatchInserter with auto-indexing feature

Tags: lucene, neo4j

I am currently using neo4j BatchInserter to massively create a big graph. Following the [examples](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert-examples.html) I chose to use the Lucene Index for the indexing of the nodes. As far as I know neo4j provides an auto-indexing feature. Is this feature available also for batch insertion? If yes will it speed up the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, auto indexing is not supported for batch inserter. However you can manually write to a index called 'node_auto_index' - which populates the auto index manually. Indexing will not speed up batch insert, in opposite indexing always trades write for read performance.

Comment: So the Lucene index is the proposed index. Lucene is fastest than the node_auto_index?

Comment: It is the same index, just with a special name `node_auto_index` and a special behavior (automatically updated on databases changes). Otherwise it is the same index.